# How to check if Phalcon MultipleLogger logged an error?

Tags: php, logging, phalcon, error-logging

I have a MultipleLogger that consists of 2 loggers. First logger writes all errors to error.log, second logger writes all messages to debug.log. I'd like to check if MultipleLogger has logged an error. Is there a method to check it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create child loggers and put additional debug info there:

```
<?php

namespace Phalcon\Logger\Adapter;

class FileExt extends \Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File
{
    ...
    public function log($message, $type = null) {
        //YOUR ADDITIONAL DEBUG LOGIC HERE
        parent::log($message, $type); 
    }

    public function debug($message) { 
        //YOUR ADDITIONAL DEBUG LOGIC HERE
        parent::debug($message); 
    }

    public function error($message) { 
        //YOUR ADDITIONAL DEBUG LOGIC HERE
        parent::error($message); 
    }
    ...
}
```

Add new logger to the DI:

```
$di->setShared('logger', function() {
    $logger = new Phalcon\Logger\Multiple();
    $logger->push(new Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\FileExt('test.log'));
    ...
    return $logger;
});
```

Or extends Phalcon\Logger\Multiple and put it into DI using same approach.